# Weird output when checking my deck of cards before each card is drawn

Tags: java, logic, output, blackjack

I don't understand why I'm getting such output. The output tries to recreate and reshuffle cards every time I draw initial card, but why? Since I'm checking if deck of cards is empty or is null and if it is, it is being created.

Why wouldn't my code work?

Output:

```
#########    BLACK    ###    JACK    #########

deal, hit, stay, exit: deal

Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing Player's card... A_♦
Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing Dealer's card... X_X
Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing Player's card... 6_♥
Creating deck...
Shuffling deck...

Drawing Dealer's card... X_X

Dealers Hand: A_♦ X_X = 11
Players Hand: 6_♥ A_♦ = 17
```

Initial Draw method:

```
private static Deck initialDraw(Deck deck, Hand player, Hand dealer)
{
    drawFromDeck(deck, player);
    drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
    drawFromDeck(deck, player);
    drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);

    System.out.print("\n");

    showHands(player, dealer);
    compareHands(player, dealer);

    return deck;
}
```

I don't get this output when I use following code, how is it different? I'm still referencing the same array and passing it back, no ?

```
private static Deck initialDraw(Deck deck, Hand player, Hand dealer)
{
    deck = checkDeck(deck);

    drawFromDeck(deck, player);
    drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
    drawFromDeck(deck, player);
    drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);

    System.out.print("\n");

    showHands(player, dealer);
    compareHands(player, dealer);

    return deck;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code from `showHands` and `checkDeck`? I think your problem lies there.

Comment: One issue is hand.getName() == "Dealer" use hand.getName().equals("Dealer")

Comment: @Nambari, I don't see any difference between them =S

Comment: instead of ==, use .equals()

Comment: @Nambari, but why? It would perform the same action in this situation.

Comment: In Java == is for primitive comparison, equals() is for Object comparison. I guess you are from .NET background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick solution**:

```
private static Deck initialDraw(Deck deck, Hand player, Hand dealer)

    {
        deck = drawFromDeck(deck, player);
        deck = drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);
        deck = drawFromDeck(deck, player);
        deck = drawFromDeck(deck, dealer);

        System.out.print("\n");

        showHands(player, dealer);
        compareHands(player, dealer);

        return deck;
    }
```

**Explanation**:

Inside `drawFromDeck` you are creating/updating the deck and returning this, but not updating the variable as seen in `initialDraw`. This may not be such an issue (since Objects are passed by reference, but test before relying on it!), but I assume you are passing `null` into `initialDraw`, and so `null` is being passed to each `drawFromDeck` call, and so a new `Deck` is created each time.

**For your Edit where you code works**

In that case, you are ensuring that `deck` is not a `null` reference, but a reference to an actual `Deck` object, and so you will be passing a reference to a `Deck` object to each `drawFromDeck` call, rather than passing a `null` reference each time.